# Reverse Geocoding with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I'm experimenting with reverse geocoding [directive](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/02/15/AngularJS-Reverse-Geocoding-Directive.aspx) in Angular and I am at the moment only available to get the lat/lng coordinates from a location but the reverse geocoding directive will only give me an error of

> Geocoder failed due to: ZERO_RESULTS

I've created a simple Plnkr example to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve that you can view [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/78SRIuBCIETEuEcdNOl5).

When using `$scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.lat = lat;
                $scope.lng = lng;
            });`

It does not matter if I use regular coordinates instead like

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.lat = 4.545;
        $scope.lng = 12.756;
    });
```

as that will only result in the same error from the reverse geocoding. I've tried experimenting with the curly braces in the index.html file

`<reverse-geocode lat="{{lat}}" lng="{{lng}}"></reverse-geocode>` but I have a strong feeling I need to edit them somehow to grab the lat/lng coords, but no luck so far

Comment: The plunkr link is already in my description. If you are unable to open it for some reason you should be able to access it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/78SRIuBCIETEuEcdNOl5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the directive will compile and execute before the asynchronous `$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` has finished, which means that inside the directive both `attrs.lat` and `attrs.lng` will be empty.

An easy solution is to prevent the directive from executing before the data is available:

```
<reverse-geocode ng-if="lat && lng" lat="{{lat}}" lng="{{lng}}"></reverse-geocode>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/mJJ8OIvff1Xspnx24LfJ?p=preview

Comment: I had a feeling it was a easy one, from the look of the Plnkr you provided it seems to be working as intended. Thank you so much @tasseKATT !